# Histogram plots in LevelScheme

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, levelscheme

I've just started using [LevelScheme](http://wnsl.physics.yale.edu/levelscheme/), and have issues with getting the histogram to fit correctly within the figure. A minimal non-working example:

```
<<"LevelScheme`"
Figure[{FigurePanel[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
   LabB -> textit["x"], BufferB -> 2.5,
   LabL -> textit["p(x)"], BufferL -> 2.5,
   FrameTicks -> {LinTicks[-4, 4], LinTicks[0, 1]},
   PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0, 0.5}}], 
  RawGraphics[
   Histogram[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 1000], Automatic, 
    "ProbabilityDensity"]]},
 Frame -> False, PlotRange -> {{-0.075, 1.1}, {-0.1, 1.03}}]
```

The output looks like this

[image]

when it should look like this

[image]

Basically, the `Histogram` graphics object doesn't obey the `FigurePanel`'s `PlotRange`, but instead obeys the main `Figure`'s `PlotRange`. This behaviour doesn't occur when the `Histogram` is replaced by a `Plot` or similar commands. So the following produces a clean plot

```
Figure[{FigurePanel[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
   LabB -> textit["x"], BufferB -> 2.5,
   LabL -> textit["p(x)"], BufferL -> 2.5,
   FrameTicks -> {LinTicks[-4, 4], LinTicks[0, 1]},
   PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0, 0.5}}], 
  RawGraphics[Plot[1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-x^2/2], {x, -4, 4}]]},
 Frame -> False, PlotRange -> {{-0.075, 1.1}, {-0.1, 1.03}}]
```

[image]

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Or, do you have suggestions for a fix?

**EDIT**

I thought I'd add some green to the question. I'm still interested in knowing how to overcome this hurdle.

Comment: Can you draw a histogram using LevelScheme's DataPlot?

Comment: @Simon: I tried that and it didn't work. It seems like its functionality is similar to `ListLinePlot`.

Comment: o'b: OK. The nice thing about LevelScheme is that the code is completely open - so maybe you can see why it fails with Histogram...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I recon you won't like this one too much but it is a workaround of sorts.

If I give `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` as a Histogram option (rather than `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"`) I disable interactive behaviour but, with a few minor tweaks, I get the following:

```
<< "LevelScheme`"
Figure[{FigurePanel[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, LabB -> textit["x"], 
   BufferB -> 2.5, LabL -> textit["p(x)"], BufferL -> 2.5, 
   FrameTicks -> {LinTicks[-4, 4], LinTicks[0, 1]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0, 0.55}}], 
  RawGraphics[
   Histogram[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 1000], Automatic, 
    "ProbabilityDensity", PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]]}, 
 Frame -> False, PlotRange -> {{-0.075, 1.1}, {-0.15, 1.1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: That is pretty neat! Would not have guessed that turning off interactive behaviour would fix it.

Comment: Does `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` lower the quality of the graph is some way, or only remove the sugar?

Comment: SWEET! I still have 5 days left on the bounty, but I think you deserve it for a short and simple fix! Enjoy your +100 and new privileges that comes along with 1000 rep.

Comment: @d'o-o'b Thanks :-) And thanks for posting the question.  LevelScheme is really excellent. I hadn't used it before, but I now find it very useful.

Answer (score 2):

As Simon mentioned in a comment, you can use `LevelScheme`'s `DataPlot` to plot a histogram.

```
<< "LevelScheme`"
histData[x_] := 
  Cases[x, RectangleBox[{bl_, _}, {br_, c_}] :> {{bl, br}, c}, 
   Infinity];
hist = histData[
   Histogram[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 1000], {-4, 4, 0.1}, 
    "ProbabilityDensity"]];
bins = hist[[All, 1, 1]]; counts = hist[[All, 2]];
data = Table[{bins[[i]], counts[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length@counts}];

Figure[{FigurePanel[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, LabB -> textit["x"], 
   BufferB -> 2.5, LabL -> textit["p(x)"], BufferL -> 2.5, 
   FrameTicks -> {LinTicks[-4, 4], LinTicks[0, 1]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0, 0.5}}],
  DataPlot[data, 
   DataLine -> {LineShape -> "Histogram", LineColor -> Darker@Blue}, 
   DataSymbol -> {SymbolSize -> 0.00001}],
  RawGraphics[
   Plot[1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-x^2/2], {x, -4, 4}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]]
  }, Frame -> False, PlotRange -> {{-0.075, 1.1}, {-0.1, 1.03}}]
```

[image]

However, I haven't managed to get filled histogram bars like that produced by `Histogram` or `BarChart`, if that was also what you had intended.

BTW, the function `histData` is similar to something I saw on a mathematica help forum long ago, and it went in my useful functions toolkit. I don't remember where I read that or when, to credit it. However, it is not all that of a magic function now to me, as it was back then.

Comment: yoda, congratulations on 4000 rep

Comment: thank you :) you're almost there... I bet by the end of the day too. I was close to around 4200 this morning, but then I found out about the rep recalc that you can trigger each day, and lost about 100+ rep when I tried. They were from deleted answers that had upvotes :( Oh well, I knew it was coming.

Comment: thank *you*, but not today I imagine.  I am in ask and ponder mode right now, and not answering many questions.

Comment: @yoda: I already tried that and it worked. See my comments to rcollyer's post where I mention that. I'm trying to recreate `Histogram`'s plot styling. What would be _really great_ is being able to call `RawGraphics[Histogram[...]]` directly instead of binning/counting, etc.

Comment: @yoda: as of v8 your dataHist has become superfluous. Now there is `HistogramList`. Before v8 you could have used the optional third argument of `Histogram` to get at the binning and count data in this way: `Reap[Histogram[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200],
  Automatic, (Sow[{#1, #2}]; #2) &]]`

Comment: @Sjoerd: I'm still using v7, so wasn't aware of `HistogramList`. Also, the `Reap` and `Sow` method is documented in mma's `Histogram` help file, and I have used it several times. However, if I remember right, it didn't work when I used the third argument to `Histogram`, which is `"ProbabilityDensity"` in this case. Of course, I could've calculated the prob-density from the bin counts myself, or I maybe I just needed to make a small change to get the output I wanted. Instead, I took the lazy man's approach and pulled out an old function that worked :)

Answer (score 1):

I know what the problem is, but I don't have an immediate fix.  The way LevelScheme works is that it transforms the `Graphics` objects so that they fit correctly.  To do this, `RawGraphics` uses the legacy function `TransformGraphics` from `LegacyPackages\Graphics\Graphics.m` which is included in `LegacyTransformGraphics.m` in v. 3.51  of the LevelScheme packages.  Looking at the `FullForm` of your `Histogram`, you can see that `TransformGraphics` knows nothing about dealing with the sort of objects produced.  Mark Caprio is working on an update to LevelScheme over the next couple of months, so there may be a fix on the way.  In the mean time, try using `Rasterize` before supply your histogram to `RawGraphics`, although it may not give you good results.

**Edit**:
Instead of using the legacy version of `TransformGraphics`, a more recent version might look like

```
TransformGraphics[ 
  (g:(Graphics | Graphics3D))[prims__, opts:OptionsPattern[], transform_]:=
    g[ GeometricTransformation[prims, transform], opts ]
```

Of course, the trick is now supplying a version of `transform` that `GeometricTransformation` can accept.  Although, the legacy `TransformGraphics`, applies a function, its second argument, directly to the points found in `g`, so using the above code may work without any additional changes.

To try it, replace `` Needs["LevelScheme`LegacyTransformGraphics`"] `` with the above code in either LevelScheme.nb (and regenerate LevelScheme.m) or in LevelScheme.m directly.  It may not work completely, as I don't see where the options are substituted, but it should be a start.

Comment: Thanks for the info, rcollyer. `Rasterize` didn't help much, but I tried playing with simon's suggestion to use `DataPlot`. It has a "Histogram" mode which sort of does the job for now (although customizing it is more involved than `Histogram`).

Comment: Sorry to hear that `Rasterize` didn't work, although I did think it would be a long shot. After looking through the code, I don't think a fix is terribly hard to implement, but it does involve figuring out how LevelScheme scales the graphics, which I haven't done, yet. :) But, I've emailed Mark at least part of a suggested fix, although it involves retooling some of the fundamentals of LevelScheme.

Comment: It doesn't plot anything now, giving the error "0 is not a graphics primitive" (I'm using v7, if it matters). I'll try fiddling around with it to see if I can get it to work. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: grrr ... have to look into it when I have more time. Let me know if you succeed. I'm using v. 7, also, and no I didn't test it before suggesting it.