# How to make a grid of plots with a single pair of FrameLabels?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot, levelscheme

What is the simplest way to create a row/column/grid of plots, with the whole grid having a single FrameLabel?

I need something similar to this:

```
p := ListPlot[RandomInteger[10, 5], Joined -> True, Axes -> False, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 11}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"horizontal", None}, AspectRatio -> 1]

GraphicsRow[{Show[p, FrameLabel -> {"horizontal", "vertical"}], p, p}]
```

For a row format, it could have one or multiple horizontal labels, but only one vertical one.

Issues to consider:

- Vertical scale must match for all plots, and must not be ruined by e.g. a too long label or automatic `PlotRangePadding`.
- Good (and resize-tolerant!) control of inter-plot spacing is needed (after all, this is one of the motivations behind removing the redundant labels)
- General space-efficiency of the arrangement. Maximum content, minimum (unnecessary) whitespace.

**EDIT**

I'm trying to be able to robustly create print ready figures, which involves a lot of resizing.  (Because the exported PDFs will usually not have the same proportions as what I see in the notebook, and must have readable but not oversized fonts)

Comment: Perhaps (graphical) examples of the issues you are trying to solve may help understanding your needs

Comment: @belisarius The code I posted can serve as example.  Try resizing the result, and see how the spacing doesn't change proportionally with the rest of the graphics.  This makes it difficult to create print-ready figures.  To illustrate what might go wrong with the vertical scaled being "out of sync", try `GraphicsRow[{Show[p, FrameLabel -> {"horizontal", "vertical vertical vertical vertical vertical vertical"}], p,p}]`

Comment: A short lived answer (deleted now by the author for some reason) suggested using `Labeled`, which seems obvious.  This is unfortunately not robust to resizing either, consider `Table[Show[Labeled[Grid[{{p, p, p}}], Rotate[Style["\tvertical", FontFamily -> "Times"], \[Pi]/2], Left], ImageSize -> s], {s, {200, 500, 1000}}]`.  Another (minor) issue with it is the centring of the label (note the `"\t"` before the label).

Comment: Szabolcs, I didn't read these comments before posting.  Is your goal graphic that scales completely proportionately, just like a raster resample?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, yes, I need something that scales "well enough", if not completely proportionally.  LevelScheme solves most annoyances I had.  (I don't mind that the text doesn't scale proportionally, in fact that's good as I can specify the size in printer's points. But I need gaps/margins to scale proportionally.)

Comment: @yoda, the question does not mention LevelScheme, and I don't think it is appropriate to tag the question based on the answer.  Is there a FAQ that says otherwise?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: No, but tags are meant for filing and for future reference and I see nothing wrong in tagging it so as long as it is not orthogonal to the question (like tagging mma with fortran). If need be, the question can be modified to include "or LevelScheme", which might make the added tag more meaningful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [LevelScheme](http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/) to achieve what you want. Here's an example:

```
<< "LevelScheme`"
Figure[{
  Multipanel[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {1, 3},
   XFrameLabels -> textit["x"], BufferB -> 3,
   YFrameLabels -> textit["Sinc(x)"], BufferL -> 3,
   TickFontSize -> 9,
   XGapSizes -> {0.1, 0.1},
   PanelLetterCorner -> {1, 1}
   ],
  FigurePanel[{1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-1.6, -0.6}, {-0.5, 1}}],
  RawGraphics[Plot[Sinc[20 x], {x, -1.6, -0.6}]],

  FigurePanel[{1, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 0.5}, {-0.5, 1}}],
  RawGraphics[Plot[Sinc[20 x], {x, -0.5, 0.5}]],

  FigurePanel[{1, 3}, PlotRange -> {{0.6, 1.6}, {-0.5, 1}}],
  RawGraphics[Plot[Sinc[20 x], {x, 0.6, 1.6}]]
  },
 PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1.02}, {-0.12, 1.095}}]
```

[image]

LevelScheme offers you tremendous flexibility in the arrangement of your plot.

- Instead of naming giving the plot common labels, you can move the definition inside the `FigurePanel[]` and control the labels for each one individually.
- You can set inter-plot spacings both in the X and Y directions and also change the sizes of each panel, for e.g., the left one can take up 2/3 of the space and the next two just 1/6 of the space each.
- You can set individual plot ranges, change the frame tick labels for each, control which side of the panel (top/bottom/l/r) the labels should be marked, change panel numberings, etc.

The only drawback is that you might have to wrestle with it in [some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465606/histogram-plots-in-levelscheme), but in general, I've found it a pleasure to use.

**EDIT**

Here's one similar to your example:

```
Figure[{
  Multipanel[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {1, 3},
   YFrameLabels -> textit["Vertical"], BufferL -> 3,
   TickFontSize -> 9,
   XGapSizes -> {0.1, 0.1},
   PanelLetterCorner -> {1, 1}
   ],
  FigurePanel[{1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {0, 10}}],
  RawGraphics[ListLinePlot[RandomInteger[10, 10]]],

  FigurePanel[{1, 2}, PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {0, 10}},
   LabB -> textit["Horizontal"], BufferB -> 3],
  RawGraphics[ListLinePlot[RandomInteger[10, 10]]],

  FigurePanel[{1, 3}, PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {0, 10}}],
  RawGraphics[ListLinePlot[RandomInteger[10, 10]]]
  },
 PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1.02}, {-0.2, 1.095}}]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2**

To answer Mr. Wizard's comment, here's a blank template for a `2x3` grid

```
Figure[{Multipanel[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {2, 3},
   XFrameTicks -> None,
   YFrameTicks -> None,
   XGapSizes -> {0.1, 0.1},
   YGapSizes -> {0.1}],
  FigurePanel[{1, 1}],
  FigurePanel[{1, 2}],
  FigurePanel[{1, 3}],
  FigurePanel[{2, 1}],
  FigurePanel[{2, 2}],
  FigurePanel[{2, 3}]
  }, PlotRange -> {{-0.01, 1.01}, {-0.01, 1.01}}]
```

[image]

And here's one with extended panels

```
Figure[{Multipanel[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {2, 3},
   XFrameTicks -> None,
   YFrameTicks -> None,
   XGapSizes -> {0.1, 0.1},
   YGapSizes -> {0.1}],
  FigurePanel[{1, 1}, PanelAdjustments -> {{0, 0}, {1.1, 0}}],
  FigurePanel[{1, 2}],
  FigurePanel[{1, 3}],
  FigurePanel[{2, 2}, PanelAdjustments -> {{0, 1.1}, {0, 0}}]
  }, PlotRange -> {{-0.01, 1.01}, {-0.01, 1.01}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of a 3x2 grid, rather than a row of three?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: please see my edit. I forgot and did a 2x3, rather than a 3x2, but the method is the same.

Comment: Well, that's what I meant, so it was my mistake.

Comment: @yoda I don't get the x-labels in the first graph. I think I see the top-pixels but that's all (MMA8/Win7-64).

Comment: @yodar Adding a `Margin -> {{0, 0}, {10, 0}}` in the first `MultiPanel` works for me.

Comment: @yoda The blank templates really help show the usefulness of your approach. Thanks for the link too.

Answer (score 9):

You already know how to handle multiple horizontal labels through `ListPlot`.
You can get single labels by using `Panel`.  For example...

```
p := ListPlot[RandomInteger[10, 5], Joined -> True, Axes -> False, 
Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 11}, AspectRatio -> 1]

Panel[GraphicsRow[{p, p, p}], {"horizontal",Rotate["vertical", Pi/2]}, 
      {Bottom, Left}, Background -> White]
```

[image: triptych]

You can optionally include labels on `Top` and `Right` edges too.

Comment: Is there a reason you have `Show[p]` rather than `p` in your code?

Comment: @Mr. I cut and pasted from the original without thinking. But now that you mention it....

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option I just put together.  Its advantage is that it is simple.

I like the look of yoda's LevelScheme plots better, assuming those can be done for a grid as well.

```
p := ListPlot[RandomInteger[10, 5], Joined -> True, Axes -> False, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 11}, AspectRatio -> 1]

gg = GraphicsGrid[{{p, p, p}, {p, p, p}, Graphics /@ Text /@ {"Left", "Center", "Right"}},
       Spacings -> 5, ItemAspectRatio -> {{1, 1, 0.15}}];

Labeled[gg, Rotate["vertical", Pi/2], Left]
```

[image]

Comment: The FontSize and FontFamily of the vertical and horizontal labels seems to be completely different

Comment: Preferable the axis tick labels should not be presented as redundant as done here. The horizontal labels in the upper row can be removed and the vertical ones in the rightmost 2x2 block can be removed as well.

Comment: @Sjoerd, the first concern could be fixed with TraditionalForm, and the second I am aware of, which is why I like yoda's solution better.  This was just a quickie.